# Command block shovel how to make it able to destroy course dirt

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to make a wooden shovel to break course dirt and I already have enter a command called `/give @p 1 0 {CanDestroy:[“”]}`, but the course dirt won't break when I want to do it.

It just says **"missingno"** when I scroll over the shovel. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use my command, this should work fine:

Unbreakable version: `/give @p minecraft:diamond_shovel{Unbreakable:1,HideFlags:8,CanDestroy:["minecraft:coarse_dirt"]} 1`

Normal version: `/give @p minecraft:diamond_shovel{HideFlags:8,CanDestroy:["minecraft:coarse_dirt"]} 1`